# Why does this asyncio.Task never finish cancelling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, python-asyncio

If I run this on the *python3* interpreter:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def wait(n):
    asyncio.sleep(n)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
fut = asyncio.async(wait(10))
fut.add_done_callback(lambda x: print('Done'))

asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
```

I get the following result:

```
{<Task pending coro=<coro() running at /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/coroutines.py:139> cb=[<lambda>() at <ipython-input-5-c72c2da2ffa4>:1]>}
```

Now if I run `fut.cancel()` I get `True` returned. But typing `fut` returns a representation of the task stating it is *cancelling*:

```
<Task cancelling coro=<coro() running at /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/coroutines.py:139> cb=[<lambda>() at <ipython-input-5-c72c2da2ffa4>:1]>
```

And the task never actually cancels (`fut.cancelled()` never returns `True`)

Why won't it cancel?

Comment: You probably actually want `yield from asyncio.sleep(n)` inside of `wait`. Otherwise, `wait` will exit without actually sleeping for `n` seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `task.cancel()` only schedules the task to be cancelled on the next run of the event loop; it doesn't immediately cancel the task, or even guarantee that the task will be actually be cancelled when the event loop runs its next iteration. This is all described [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel):

> **cancel()**
>
> Request that this task cancel itself.
>
> This arranges for a `CancelledError` to be thrown into the wrapped
>   coroutine on the next cycle through the event loop. The coroutine then
>   has a chance to clean up or even deny the request using
>   try/except/finally.
>
> Unlike `Future.cancel()`, this does not guarantee that the task will be
>   cancelled: the exception might be caught and acted upon, delaying
>   cancellation of the task or preventing cancellation completely. The
>   task may also return a value or raise a different exception.
>
> **Immediately after this method is called, `cancelled()` will not return
>   `True`** (unless the task was already cancelled). A task will be marked as
>   cancelled when the wrapped coroutine terminates with a `CancelledError`
>   exception (even if `cancel()` was not called).

In your case, you're never actually starting the event loop, so the task  never gets cancelled. You would need to call `loop.run_until_complete(fut)` (or `loop.run_forever()`, though that's not really the best choice for this particular case) for the task to actually end up getting cancelled.

Also, for what it's worth, it's usually easier to test `asyncio` code using actual scripts, rather than the interpreter, since it tends to get tedious to have to constantly rewrite coroutines and start/stop the event loop.

Comment: I think the perfect answer would combine mine own with this one. If you combine them on yours I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

With *asyncio* testing in the interpreter is tricky, because python needs to keep the event loop constantly polling its tasks.

So a few pieces of advice to test *asyncio* are:

1. Write and run scripts instead of using the interactive interpreter
2. Add a `loop.run_forever()` at the end of the script so all tasks get executed.
3. An alternative is to run `loop.run_until_complete(coro())` for each task you want to run.
4. Have `yield from` in front of `asyncio.sleep(n)` so it can actually be run. The current code returns a generator and does nothing.